# JSSOR display label of current image as thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I am using [jssor](http://www.jssor.com/). I currently have a slider with **thumbnails** and  **arrows**.

I would like to keep the 2 arrows but instead of images, to display **text** and only **one label text**  related to the image. 
Something like the following:
[image: jssor-text-label]

Can this be achieved from within [jssor](http://www.jssor.com/)?

## UPDATED description

I have 6 images that are sliding, I want to display one image label on each image. If i try :

```
<div u="thumb">your text</div>
```

it puts 6 texts , i only want to show the text of the current image only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two approaches to reach your goal,

1. Use thumbnail navigator in text format.

   Example 1: http://www.jssor.com/skin/thumbnail-09.source.html
   Example 2: http://www.jssor.com/skin/thumbnail-10.source.html
2. Add content element in each individual slide.

   ```
   <div u="slides" ...>
     <div>
         <img u="image" .../>
         <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 30px; color: #fff; background-color: #000; line-height: 30px;">
             your text 1
         </div>
     </div>
     <div>
         <img u="image" .../>
         <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 30px; color: #fff; background-color: #000; line-height: 30px;">
             your text 2
         </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely!

Thumbnail is not only image, it can be everything.

You can use

```
<img u="thumb" ... />
```

And also, you can use any html code like below.

```
<div u="thumb">your text</div>
```

Please just go for it, and post your question here if there is still problem.

Comment: Thanks, i did try that already, please check my updated description